# NLTK - when to normalize the text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I've finished gathering my data I plan to use for my corpus, but I'm a bit confused about whether I should normalize the text. I plan to tag & chunk the corpus in the future. Some of NLTK's corpora are all lower case and others aren't.

Can anyone shed some light on this subject, please?

Answer (score 9):

By "normalize" do you just mean making everything lowercase?

The decision about whether to lowercase everything is really dependent of what you plan to do.  For some purposes, lowercasing everything is better because it lowers the sparsity of the data (uppercase words are rarer and might confuse the system unless you have a massive corpus such that the statistics on capitalized words are decent).  In other tasks, case information might be valuable.

Additionally, there are other considerations you'll have to make that are similar.  For example, should `"can't"` be treated as `["can't"]`, `["can", "'t"]`, or `["ca", "n't"]` (I've seen all three in different corpora).  What about `7-year-old`?  Is it one long word?  Or three words that should be separated?

That said, there's no reason to reformat the corpus.  You can just have your code make these changes on the fly.  That way the original information is still around later if you ever need it.

Comment: "For most purposes" is not true: text classifiers will want lowercase input, but POS taggers, NER modules and parsers use case information to their advantage. NER is practically impossible without case information (at least for English).

Comment: @larsmans Good points.  All good things to think about when trying to decide what you want to do with your data.

Comment: The differences in "can't" are due to the chosen/default tokenizer, and shouldn't be reflected in the actual raw corpus text. But it's definitely an important thing to think about, which is why I put up a NLTK tokenizer demo at http://text-processing.com/demo/tokenize/ so it's easier to decide on which tokenizer to use.